Export tables in Database to Excel, losing times in date format
Im using the "Export tables to Excel" function in Anylogic. The export works but when I open the Excel file, all columns which are formated in the Date format in Anylogic consists only the date without any times (yyyy-MM-dd iso yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss).
Here is a picture of the table in the database of Anylogic:

And that is the same data in the exported Excel file:

What is the problem here?

No problem, change the Excel column format to display time as well :)
